# Read a file locked by another program

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs, lock

I have a program that reads a file written by another program, but that software locks the file while writing to it (I cannot even copy the file!). How can I read the file while the other program has it open?

I'm using Windows 7 with NTFS filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the nature behaviors for Windows system because the file is currently accessing by the program. If you want to force to take ownership of the file, you may try to use [Unlocker](http://filehippo.com/zh/download_unlocker/), please note that it depends on what program are you using, some program will crash or abnormal if you force to unlock the file.